# Graphical Modelling Framework does not work with Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-indigo, eclipse-gmf

I am following the [GMF Tutorial](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Graphical_Modeling_Framework/Tutorial/Part_1) in Eclipse Indigo, MacOSX. The following error occurred in the step to create the generator model: mindmap.gmfgen. In Eclipse Helios, there is no problem at all.

I am new to GMF, please help me fix it!

```
  Errors while creating generator model 

java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.eclipse.ocl.ecore.EcoreEvaluationEnvironment.<init>(EcoreEvaluationEnvironment.java:118)
at org.eclipse.m2m.internal.qvt.oml.ast.env.QvtOperationalEvaluationEnv.<init>(QvtOperationalEvaluationEnv.java:73)
at org.eclipse.m2m.internal.qvt.oml.ast.env.QvtOperationalEnvFactory.createEvaluationEnvironment(QvtOperationalEnvFactory.java:129)
at org.eclipse.gmf.internal.xpand.model.ExecutionContextImpl.createEvaluationEnvironment(ExecutionContextImpl.java:305)
at org.eclipse.gmf.internal.xpand.model.ExecutionContextImpl.createEvaluationVisitor(ExecutionContextImpl.java:281)
at org.eclipse.gmf.internal.xpand.ocl.ExpressionHelper.evaluate(ExpressionHelper.java:98)
at org.eclipse.gmf.internal.xpand.ast.ExpressionStatement.evaluateInternal(ExpressionStatement.java:39)
at org.eclipse.gmf.internal.xpand.ast.Statement.evaluate(Statement.java:29)
at org.eclipse.gmf.internal.xpand.ast.AbstractDefinition.evaluate(AbstractDefinition.java:82)
at org.eclipse.gmf.internal.xpand.XpandFacade.evaluate(XpandFacade.java:68)
at org.eclipse.gmf.graphdef.codegen.FigureGenerator.go(FigureGenerator.java:99)
at org.eclipse.gmf.internal.bridge.genmodel.InnerClassViewmapProducer.createViewmap(InnerClassViewmapProducer.java:128)
at org.eclipse.gmf.internal.bridge.genmodel.InnerClassViewmapProducer.create(InnerClassViewmapProducer.java:76)
at org.eclipse.gmf.internal.bridge.genmodel.DiagramGenModelTransformer.process(DiagramGenModelTransformer.java:274)
at org.eclipse.gmf.internal.bridge.genmodel.MappingTransformer.transform(MappingTransformer.java:31)
at org.eclipse.gmf.internal.bridge.transform.TransformToGenModelOperation$2.process(TransformToGenModelOperation.java:421)
at org.eclipse.gmf.internal.bridge.transform.TransformToGenModelOperation.executeTransformation(TransformToGenModelOperation.java:264)
at org.eclipse.gmf.internal.bridge.transform.TransformToGenModelWizard$1.run(TransformToGenModelWizard.java:161)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.runInCurrentThread(ModalContext.java:464)
at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext.run(ModalContext.java:372)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.run(WizardDialog.java:1029)
at org.eclipse.gmf.internal.bridge.transform.TransformToGenModelWizard.performFinish(TransformToGenModelWizard.java:164)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.finishPressed(WizardDialog.java:827)
at org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardDialog.buttonPressed(WizardDialog.java:432)
at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog$2.widgetSelected(Dialog.java:624)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:240)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4128)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1457)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1480)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1465)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1270)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3974)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3613)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:825)
at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:801)
at org.eclipse.gmf.internal.bridge.transform.TransformToGenModelAction.run(TransformToGenModelAction.java:72)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.PluginAction.runWithEvent(PluginAction.java:251)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(ActionContributionItem.java:584)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem.access$2(ActionContributionItem.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.ActionContributionItem$5.handleEvent(ActionContributionItem.java:411)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4128)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1457)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1480)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1465)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.notifyListeners(Widget.java:1270)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:3974)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3613)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:123)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)


eclipse.buildId=M20110909-1335
java.version=1.6.0_26
java.vendor=Apple Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=macosx, ARCH=x86, WS=cocoa, NL=it_IT
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.modeling.product -product         org.eclipse.epp.package.modeling.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.modeling.product -keyring /Users/fx/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
Command-line arguments:  -os macosx -ws cocoa -arch x86 -product     org.eclipse.epp.package.modeling.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.modeling.product -data /Users/fx/workspaces/examples/gmf/ -product org.eclipse.epp.package.modeling.product -keyring /Users/fx/.eclipse_keyring -showlocation
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [this site](http://download.eclipse.org/modeling/gmp/gmf-tooling/updates/releases/) for Indigo GMF tooling

...which was mentioned [here](http://mickaelistria.wordpress.com/2011/10/28/gmf-tooling-and-its-2-4-0-for-indigo-release-are-in-da-place/)